# Fail to retrieve the web element object

Tags: python, html

when I tried to extract the table in investing.com historical data, I can't retrieve the column item and an error occur

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-119-ba739f477693>", line 2, in <module>
    col = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[0]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

`rows = table_id.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")`

successfully extracted all the rows of the table, but when i tried to loop over each row and output the first column item, above error occurred.

I further checked that the first column item in the second row is below web element

```
"selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="760e711c6189c07f6986103c1374ce13", element="0.5172974513607607-24")"

from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'chromedriver.exe')

browser.get("https://www.investing.com/commodities/brent-oil-historical-data")

table_id = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[(@id = "curr_table")]')

rows = table_id.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")

for row in rows:

    col = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[0] #e.g. get the first col

    print (col.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below way of fetching element. I have just changed the way you are fetching table and row.

```
WebElement table_id = driver.findElement**(By.xpath("//table[@id='curr_table']/tbody")**);

List<WebElement> rows = table_id.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));  
for (WebElement row : rows){
    List<WebElement> col = row.findElements(By.tagName("td")); 
     **System.out.println(col.get(0).getText());**
```

Comment: thanks your help, i tried to change the curr_table to result_box, but the issue still happened. i hv no ideas why, i can see the web element but just can't do anything...

Comment: Can you share the output of table_id and rows.

Comment: i use this //*[@id="results_box"] xpath, then the output of table_id is, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="760e711c6189c07f6986103c1374ce13", element="0.5172974513607607-31")>

Comment: and then the first 2 row elements are [<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="760e711c6189c07f6986103c1374ce13", element="0.5172974513607607-2")>,
 <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="760e711c6189c07f6986103c1374ce13", element="0.5172974513607607-3")>]

Comment: I have updated the answer above, That should work for you.